# Ошибка HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily в Delphi

Tags: delphi, indy

```
try
    Memo1.Clear;
    WebBrowser1.Silent:=True;
    idHttp1:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    c:=IdHTTP1.Get(WebBrowser1.LocationURL);
    d:=Utf8ToAnsi(c);
    Memo1.Text:=d;
except

end;
```

При нажатие на клавишу в Memo1 должен добавится Html код с текущей страницы WebBrowser1.
Иногда программа работает правильно, а иногда выдает ошибку. Я заметил, что такое происходит после того когда я залогиниваюсь на сайте.
Как пофиксить эту ошибку?

Comment: асоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577900/what-should-i-do-about-302-found-exceptions-when-downloading-with-indy

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно в компоненте разрешить переадресацию

```
idhttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil); 
try 
  idhttp.HandleRedirects := True;
  c := idhttp.Get(WebBrowser1.LocationURL);
  d := Utf8ToAnsi(c);
  Memo1.Text:=d;
finally 
  idhttp.Free; 
end;
```

Comment: Оно перестало выдавать ошибку, но HtMl код не соответствует той странице на которой я нахожусь. Оно выдает код из стартовой страницы сайта.

Comment: @AlexLovin Скорее всего у вас нет прав на просмотр этой страницы

Comment: Ну как нету прав, если я ее открыл в WebBrowser1?

Comment: @AlexLovin Просто взяли и открыли? Или вводили какие-нибудь пароли?

Comment: С паролями, я залогинился,и попробовал достать HTML код

Comment: @AlexLovin Залогинились через IdHTTP?

Comment: Нет, расскажите как правильно залогиниться.

Comment: @AlexLovin Послать запрос идентичный тому, что посылает браузер